# How to style this triangle on a circular image?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am using bootstrap 3.3 in my project, I would like to style the photo using CSS. please guide me how can to do this?

The preview (what I need):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `svg`'s `clipPath` and `filter`s for the `box-shadow`.

---

The co-ordinates for the triangle were calculated using the formula for a co-ordinate on a circle:

`(x, y) = (r × cos(θ), r × sin(θ))` where, `r` is the radius of a circle and `θ` is the angle.

The co-ordinate that is not on the circle was assumed to be a co-ordinate on a circle with radius `55px`, which is `5px` more than the original circle's radius(`50px`).

---

#### Complete Explaination:

[image]

#### My favourite part - Math:

```
  
(x1, y1) = (ra × cos(θ), ra × sin(θ))
         = (50px × cos(30°), 50px × sin(30°))
         = (43.30px, 25px)

(a1, b1) = (rb × cos(θ), rb × sin(θ))
         = (55px × cos(40°), 55px × sin(40°))
         = (42.13px, 35.35px)

(x2, y2) = (ra × cos(θ), ra × sin(θ))
         = (50px × cos(50°), 50px × sin(50°))
         = (32.14px, 38.30px)

######################################################################################################
##                                                                                                  ##
## At this point, these co-ordinates' origin is the center of the circle, but we need it to be the  ##
## top left corner, so we add the radius of the circle to the co-ordinates as well.                 ##
##                                                                                                  ##
######################################################################################################

(ra + x1, ra + y1) = (50px + 43.30px, 50px + 25px)    = (93.30px, 75px)
(rb + a1, rb + b1) = (55px + 42.13px, 55px + 35.35px) = (97.13px, 90.35px)
(ra + x2, ra + y2) = (50px + 32.14px, 50px + 38.30px) = (82.14px, 88.30px)
```

Now, compare the co-ordinates `(93.30px, 75px)`, `(97.13px, 90.35px)` and `(82.14px, 88.30px)` with `M93,75 L97,90 L82,88`.

So, that's how I calculated the co-ordinates.

---

```html
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M50,50 m-50,0 a50,50 0 0,0 82,38 M93,75 L97,90 L82,88 M0,50 a50,50 0 1,1 93,25z M0,50 L93,75 L82,88z" />
    </clipPath>
    <filter id="boxshadow" width="140%" height="140%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="6" />
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="5" result="offsetblur" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path filter="url(#boxshadow)" d="M50,50 m-50,0 a50,50 0 0,0 82,38 M93,75 L97,90 L82,88 M0,50 a50,50 0 1,1 93,25" fill="none" stroke="#F3FEF8" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

---

#### Applying this effect to multiple images:

The `clipPath` and `filter` are in `defs` tags, which means you are defining them and they only need to be defined once if you wish to use them multiple times on your page.

Also, the `path` element with `id="border"` is always going to be same for identical image sizes and to re-use it on the page you could use the `use` tag giving it a reference of the original `path` element like so:

```
<use xlink:href="#border" />
```

So, you don't have to repeat the same `path` element everytime you add a border.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M50,50 m-50,0 a50,50 0 0,0 82,38 M93,75 L97,90 L82,88 M0,50 a50,50 0 1,1 93,25z M0,50 L93,75 L82,88z" />
    </clipPath>
    <filter id="boxshadow" width="140%" height="140%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="6" />
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="5" result="offsetblur" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <path id="border" filter="url(#boxshadow)" d="M50,50 m-50,0 a50,50 0 0,0 82,38 M93,75 L97,90 L82,88 M0,50 a50,50 0 1,1 93,25" fill="none" stroke="#F3FEF8" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg width="125" height="120" viewBox="-12 -8 124 124">
  <use xlink:href="#border" />
  <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: i have to display multiple images in a block, if i used this code. i see here the id's shape, boxshadow, sourceGraphic are become duplicate. so this is not issue right?

Comment: @veblearner - I'll show you how you can display multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use use two images for the `triangle` and the `circle` you can use `background-image` or you can use `img` and place them accordingly by `position:absolute`, In the below example I have use `background-img`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(199, 206, 212);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://i745.photobucket.com/albums/xx93/ily_cin/DSC03085.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(http://i745.photobucket.com/albums/xx93/ily_cin/DSC03085.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: -71px -77px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(199, 206, 212);
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.41);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it:-

```
<img class="img-circle box-shad" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
```

CSS:-

```
.box-shad {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

Real answer was given by Irvin [Bootstrap Image Circle Inner Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301769/bootstrap-image-circle-inner-shadow)

Comment: i know that image cirlce, but i need that tail end style