# How to create a circle with links on border side

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am trying to make a circle like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ns3bc9h/1/). I was able to make it in the fiddle, but the problem is that I need each orange side to be a link and I can't do it with borders. If anyone can help me with this I will be really grateful.

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}
#incircle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 50px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="incircle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @chipChocolate.py No each orange border must be different links

Comment: _"i need each orange side to be a link"_ - Do you mean the left and right sides should be two different links?

Comment: Are you particular about the shape of each orange colored area too? I mean their inner part looks like an arc.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: I guess OP intends it to be like a fortune wheel with each boxed area being a unique item.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py There are six orange fig there and each should be a link leading to different places

Comment: @Harry Yes there shapes are the one that's troubling me it is a bit hard

Comment: I only see one orange shape, not six. In the event you want shapes like the ones on a spinning fortune wheel, I suggest you use SVG graphics as you can link to certain shapes inside the SVG, or use a drawing library such as Rafael (http://raphaeljs.com/) or Paper.js (http://paperjs.org/)

Comment: See @the8472's answer below, he has the same idea and I believe it will be the best solution.

Comment: @SimonDowdles Thanks i will have a look at it

Comment: what about a map ? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Just thought i'd place [this](http://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xzhBw) here...

Comment: @jbutler483 That is really good nice thinking

Comment: @Akshay: I was having more fun with spinning that than I was coding an answer!! haha

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56797060/8620333

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key to creating a circle with segments is to find points along the circle which would be used in the SVG `path` elements as coordinates. Finding points on a circle can be done easily using trigonometric equations if we know the angles.

> X Coordinate of point = Radius of the circle * Cos(Angle in Radians) + X Coordinate of center point
>
> Y Coordinate of point = Radius of the circle * Sin(Angle in Radians) + Y Coordinate of center point
>
> Angle in Radians = Angle in Degrees * Math.PI / 180

The angles depend on the no. of segments that we have to create. The generic formula is (360 / no. of segments). So to create a circle with 6 segments, the angle covered by each of the segment would be 60 degrees. The first segment would cover from 0 to 60 degrees, second from 60 to 120 degrees and so on.

---

**Demo of Circle with 6 Segments:**

Below table shows how the points are calculated for a circle with 6 segments (where radius of circle is 50, center point is 55,55):

[image]

Once the points are calculated, coding the `path` itself is simple. The path should start and end at the center point (which is 50,50), from the center point, we should first draw a line to From Point and from there draw an arc to the To Point. Below is how a sample `path` would look like:

```
<path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
```

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
</svg>
```

---

**Demo of Circle with 12 Segments:**

For a circle with 12 segments, each segment would cover 30 degrees and so the points would be calculated as in the below table:

[image]

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 98.30,80z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L98.30,80 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 55,105z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L55,105 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 11.69,80z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L11.69,80 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 11.69,30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L11.69,30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 55,5z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L55,5 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 98.30,30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L98.30,30 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
</svg>
```

---

**Circle with an unsegmented inner portion:**

If it should look as though a portion of the circle (with a smaller radius) in center looks unsegmented and if that **inner portion need not be transparent**, just add an extra circle element at the end within the SVG.

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
circle {
  fill: yellowgreen;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
  <circle cx='55' cy='55' r='25' />
</svg>
```

---

**Different Background for each Segment:**

If each of the segments should have a different background to them then just add the `fill` attribute to each `path` element.

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
}
circle {
  fill: yellowgreen;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' fill='crimson' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' fill='tomato' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' fill='sandybrown' />
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' fill='mediumseagreen' />
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' fill='chocolate' />
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' fill='teal' />
  <circle cx='55' cy='55' r='25' />
</svg>
```

---

**Demo with a transparent inner portion:**

If the center portion cannot have a solid color then the whole thing becomes  more complex because we can no longer start and end the path at the center point. In such cases, we have to find points on both the outer circle and the inner circle like below:

[image]

In this case, the `path` has to start from the "From(Inner)" and end at same point, from the start a line should be drawn to "From(Outer)", then an arc to "To(Outer)", a line to "To(Inner)" and an arc to "From (Inner)".

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M80,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30 L67.5,76.65 A25,25 0 0,0 80,55z' />
  <path d='M67.5,76.65 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30 L42.5,76.65 A25,25 0 0,0 67.5,76.65z' />
  <path d='M42.5,76.65 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55 L30,55 A25,25 0 0,0 42.5,76.65z' />
  <path d='M30,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69 L42.5,33.34 A25,25 0 0,0 30,55z' />
  <path d='M42.5,33.34 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69 L67.5,33.34 A25,25 0 0,0 42.5,33.34z' />
  <path d='M67.5,33.34 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55 L80,55 A25,25 0 0,0 67.5,33.4z' />
</svg>
```

---

**Making each segment a clickable link:**

This is pretty simple to do once the shape itself has been created. Like in chipChocolate.py's answer, just wrap each path within a SVG anchor tag (`<a xlink:href="#">` where `#` should be replaced the URL of the linked page).

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' /></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' /></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' /></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' /></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' /></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' /></a>
</svg>
```

---

**Adding text within the shape:**

Text addition in SVG is slightly more complex because again we have to specify the point where the text should be placed. If the text is reasonably small (say a few characters), then we can again find points on the circle such that the angle is exactly in the middle of the segment and use it. The radius could be set such that it is half the parent circle's radius (if there is no unsegmented portion) or such that it is half way between the inner circle and outer circle. The `text-anchor`, `dominant-baseline` settings that are added via CSS would make sure that the text is positioned in such a way that both the horizontal and vertical center of the text matches with the specified point.

If the text is large (and needs to wrap around), then extra handling should be done because contents within the SVG `text` tag won't get wrapped around automatically.

Point calculation for circle with 6 segments and no central unsegmented area:

[image]

Point calculation for circle with 6 segments and central unsegmented area:

[image]

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle; /* doesn't work in IE */
  font: 12px Calibri, Arial;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <text x='76.65' y='67.5'>1</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <text x='55' y='80'>2</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <text x='33.4' y='67.5'>3</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <text x='33.4' y='42.5'>4</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <text x='55' y='30'>5</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
  <text x='76.65' y='42.5'>6</text>
</svg>
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  <path d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <text x='87.47' y='73.75'>1</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <text x='55' y='92.5'>2</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <text x='22.52' y='73.75'>3</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <text x='22.52' y='36.25'>4</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <text x='55' y='17.5'>5</text>
  <path d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
  <text x='87.47' y='36.25'>6</text>
  <circle cx='55' cy='55' r='25' />
</svg>
```

---

**Dynamic creation with JavaScript:**

Below is a rough JS based implementation in order to create the segments dynamically. The function takes four arguments - the X coordinate of the circle's center, the Y coordinate of its center, the radius of the circle and the no. of segments/slices.

```js
var fromAngle, toAngle, fromCoordX, fromCoordY, toCoordX, toCoordY, path, d;

function createPie(cx, cy, r, slices) {
  for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    fromAngle = i * 360 / slices;
    toAngle = (i + 1) * 360 / slices;
    fromCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    fromCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    d = 'M' + cx + ',' + cy + ' L' + fromCoordX + ',' + fromCoordY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0,1 ' + toCoordX + ',' + toCoordY + 'z';
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
    document.getElementById('pie').appendChild(path);
  }
}

createPie(55, 55, 50, 6);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 110 110" id="pie"></svg>
```

JS sample doesn't cover the examples with an unsegmented inner circle but that can be achieved by extending this.

Comment: Is there a way we could generate this with javascript?

Comment: Yes @inspired. It is definitely possible but I'm quite busy at the moment and so can't provide a demo. All that you'd need to do is find out the co-ordinates based on the formula, concatenate them into a string (to form the value of `d` attribute) and then set that attribute to the `path` element. I'll post a demo when I get some free time,

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know when you do so. I'll make one for myself and show it to you when i'm done today.

Comment: @inspired: [Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/NRyPBz) is a rough demo with JavaScript. I am sure you will be able to extend this in case you need an inner circle that is unsegmented :)

Comment: why do to simple, if could be much more complicated? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640359/961631

Answer (score 19):

You could use `svg`'s `arc`s to create the sections and `svg`'s anchor(equivalent to HTML anchor tags) tags for the links.

[image]

```css
.frag {
  fill: #FFA500;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: fill 0.3s ;
}
.center {
  fill: #008000;
}
a:hover .frag {
  fill: #FFC722;
}
text {
  font-size: 17px;
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 v-100 a100,100 1 0,1 86.6025,50" /><text x="135" y="42.5" text-anchor="middle">1</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,100" /><text x="170" y="105" text-anchor="middle">2</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,50" /><text x="135" y="170" text-anchor="middle">3</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 v100 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,-50" /><text x="65" y="170" text-anchor="middle">4</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,-100" /><text x="27.5" y="105" text-anchor="middle">5</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 86.0025,-50" /><text x="65" y="42.5" text-anchor="middle">6</text></a>
  <a xlink:href="#"><path class="center" d="M100,100 v-50 a50,50 1 0,1 0,100 a50,50 1 0,1 0,-100" /></a>
</svg>
```

---

You could also stretch or resize the `svg`.

[image]

```css
.frag {
  fill: #FFA500;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: fill 0.3s ;
}
.center {
  fill: #008000;
}
a:hover .frag {
  fill: #FFC722;
}
text {
  font-size: 17px;
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="200" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <g id="circle">
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 v-100 a100,100 1 0,1 86.6025,50" /><text x="135" y="42.5" text-anchor="middle">1</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,100" /><text x="170" y="105" text-anchor="middle">2</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,50" /><text x="135" y="170" text-anchor="middle">3</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 v100 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,-50" /><text x="65" y="170" text-anchor="middle">4</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,-100" /><text x="27.5" y="105" text-anchor="middle">5</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 86.0025,-50" /><text x="65" y="42.5" text-anchor="middle">6</text></a>
    <a xlink:href="#"><path class="center" d="M100,100 v-50 a50,50 1 0,1 0,100 a50,50 1 0,1 0,-100" /></a>
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>

<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <use xlink:href="#circle" />
</svg>
```

Comment: it seem useful but it doesn't look like the provided example .

Comment: @chipChocolate.py If you saw what the OP provided as expected design, you should know what I mean ^^.

Comment: @Hacketo - OP marked the question as accepted. I believe he got what he was looking for, Period! If he has any problem with the current design, I'm more than happy to re-design it. :)

Comment: I need 11 sections instead of 6. What should be changed in the code?

Comment: @maruf - You need to calculate each co-ordinate and apply accordingly in the `d` attribute of `path` element. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27645600/3905567) might help. I will make a JavaScript function to make sections arbitrarily and post it in my answer.

Comment: @Weafs.py The space between 6 or 1 is not accurate. I have added stroke-width: 4; space between is not coming properly Can you please help me out how we can fix this problem.

Comment: @Husna - [Here's what you're after :)](http://dabblet.com/gist/5d35b01d675ca70d7ecf50700e978cc5)

Answer (score 11):

### CSS-only approach

**NOTE: Markup can be significantly reduced by using pseudoelements, which I haven't currently used.**

You can use ***SVG***, but this ***can be made with CSS and HTML alone.***

What I did was create `12` semicircles (by adding `overflow: hidden;` to parent container). I then created separate groups of `6` semicircles.

The angles at the center should be `30deg` each ( `360/12` ). To achieve this, we have to rotate the semicircles from their original circle's center. We can do this with `transform-origin: 50% 100%;`

Now you just have to rotate/flip the second group of `6` semicircles to complete design.

Finally, add a central green circle to complete the design.

```css
.cont, #bag {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border-radius:200px;
}
#bag > div {
    position:relative;
    transform-origin:50% 100%;
}
#one, #three, #five {
    background-color:orange;
}
#one:hover, #three:hover, #five:hover {
    background-color:gold;
}
#two, #four, #six {
    background-color:forestgreen;
}
#bag > :nth-child(2) {
    top:-200px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    transform:rotate(30deg);
}
#bag > :nth-child(3) {
    top:-400px;
    transform:rotate(60deg);
    transform:rotate(60deg);
}
#bag > div:nth-child(4) {
    top:-600px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
#bag > :nth-child(5) {
    top:-800px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
    transform:rotate(120deg);
}
#bag > :nth-child(6) {
    top:-1000px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
    transform:rotate(150deg);
}
#bag:nth-of-type(2){
    transform:scale(-1);
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
#green-center {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:forestgreen;
    position: relative;
    top:-300px;
    left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bag">
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="one"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="two">ABC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="three"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="four"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="five"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="six"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bag">
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="one"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="three"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="four"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <a href="http://example.com/"><div id="five"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div id="six"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="green-center">
```

Output on **Firefox**, **Google Chrome** and **IE**:

[image]

Comment: you have completely broke his design ^^

Comment: I don't get it. What did you mean by that? My english is not very good.

Comment: Just run the "code snippet" of the OP ask and compare with the result you suggest

Comment: Appreciate the effort you have putting in getting this done with just CSS. Excellent work. But a note of caution to future readers, such complex shapes are better achieved using SVG or other techniques as CSS wasn't really designed for such sort of things.

Comment: @Harry Thanks! I took like half an hour just to make this shape! I think with SVG it can be done in just about 5-10 mins.

Comment: That is really great i never thought that it was possible with css thanks +1

Comment: @Akshay Thanks! If more sides are needed (orange ones), you simply have to calculate the degree and rotate. Btw doesn't this apply better to your original question?

Comment: @ThePragmatick Yes got it i accepted his answer because it is not that complex your is really good and is worth a green tick but there is only one tick right.. but for your effort +2

Comment: If you want to discuss about this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68886/room-for-akshay-and-the-pragmatick

Answer (score 3):

Try this pure css:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;padding: 0; margin: 0}
nav,nav:before{
    border-radius:50%;
    background:green
}
nav{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}
nav:before{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)
}
#incircle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:50px dotted orange;
}

nav a{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent
}
nav a:nth-child(3),nav a:nth-child(4){
    left: 70px;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent
}

nav a:first-child{
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid orange
}
nav a:nth-child(2){
    left: 20px;
    border-left: 100px solid orange;
    top: 20px;
    transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
nav a:nth-child(3){
    transform: rotateZ(30deg);
    top: 0px;
    left: 86px;
    border-top: 100px solid orange;
}
nav a:nth-child(4){
    left: 46px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid orange;
    bottom: -4px;
    transform: rotateZ(28deg);
}
nav a:nth-child(5){
    right: 24px;
    border-right: 100px solid orange;
    bottom: 20px;
    transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
nav a:last-child{
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 100px solid orange
}
```

```html
<nav> 
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: from using borders- I feel it could be loosing definition between the green and orange sections. But still, it's better than my solution (IMO)

Comment: Yea same thing as @jbutler483 mentions. The link area has expanded wide off the mark.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a map, like this :

```css
#circle{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:green;
}

#mappinglink{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#incircle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:50px dotted orange;
    border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
    <div id="incircle"></div>
    <img id="mappinglink" width="200" height="200" usemap="#mymap" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/>
    <map name="mymap">
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="29,28,71,3,84,50,64,64" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="148,12,122,55,142,73,184,46" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="149,96,199,93,192,142,146,121" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="105,149,128,141,159,180,112,200" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="59,133,79,147,65,193,23,164" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
        <area  alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="48,87,50,108,3,120,4,71" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach. But since you define a fixed no. of points, a considerable amount of area is not under the link (towards the outer circumference.)

Comment: Don't understand, that's what the OP was looking for if you see the provided example in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4ns3bc9h/16/)

HTML

```
<div id="circle">
    <a id='left' href='left'></a>
    <a id='right' href='right'></a>
    <div id="mid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 49%;
    background: orange;
    display: block;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

#mid {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    border: 4px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 24%;
    top: 24%;
}
```

This can be trivially expanded to 4 parts instead of 2 by splitting up the `a`'s vertically. However I recommend you look at something like [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)
. You could even cheat and use a [pie chart](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html)!

Comment: Thanks a that was good but i need space between them if i try it with border it almost works except that even the space will become links

Comment: @Akshay, here is another where the borders don't link: http://jsfiddle.net/4ns3bc9h/16/

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use pure css, 
And came up with this:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}
.slice {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 200px solid blue;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}
.part2 {
  border-left: 200px solid red;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}
.part3 {
  border-left: 200px solid pink;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: -100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" class="slice"></a>
  <div class="slice part2"></div>
  <a href="#" class="slice part3"></a>
</div>
```

However, this is using the "border trick" to generate the blue div, and this would make part of it clickable. However, I do feel this *when adapted,* ***could*** work.

- Or, if you were interested/open to using SCSS [this](http://codepen.io/schoenwaldnils/pen/JnIKA)
- Or, you could use [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/) as a basis for your design

Something like

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  
  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
@import "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

body {
  background: #39D;
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

}

.circle a:hover {
  color: #eef;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #dde;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}

/* Author stuff */
h1.author {
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1.author a {
  color: #348;
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1.author a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-asterisk fa-2x"></a>
  </div>
  
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for SVG. It has its own type of [`<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) that can contain arbitrary shapes.