# CSS3 circle with clickable items jQuery(Radial Menu)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

Where can I find an example to create a circle like this with css3 and jQuery (for navigation)
There should be text (html) in the center
When you click (or hover) the next item, the center content should change, and also the background color

[image]

Comment: A similar question was asked few hours ago. ----> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943053/how-to-create-a-circle-with-links-on-border-side. Also, the text on the circle would be much easier using the text on path functionality of `svg`.

Comment: This is called a radial menu. That should help your searching.

Comment: when I search for radial menu, it get totally different results that doens't realy help

Comment: Then you have reading problems. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=radial+menu+css

Comment: [research = none](http://codepen.io/search?q=circular+menu&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false)

Comment: @jbutler483 I found this too, but none of them are what I need, I need text (html!) in the center, and html in the circle parts, I don't think this is possible with svg

Comment: @Ruben: the second snippet is placing html in the center? could you not adapt tht?

Comment: @jbutler483 the second one for me is this one: http://codepen.io/CreativePunch/pen/lAHiu, but it does not have text in the center? This one (http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Bzuti) is close to what I need, I can add the text in the center part, but the css is too complicated I tried changing it but I just can't

Comment: @chipChocolate.py When I look at the solutions for this question, I can't access the center. And using the svg path functionallity does not work with html (at least not in the examples I tried, don't really know how svg works myself)

Comment: @Ruben - Ofcourse you can't use text on path on html elements, but there are `svg` equivalents like `text`, `textspan`, `a`,etc...

Comment: Upside down text is **bad** UX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[forked from codepen](http://codepen.io/shubhra/pen/CchBA)

```css
/**
 * Circular menu v2
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html { font: 100%/1.3 Century Gothic, Verdana, sans-serif; }
body { overflow: hidden; min-width: 20em; }
.menuopt { display: none; }
.circle, .circle:before, .circle:after { border-radius: 50%; }
nav {
 margin: 5em auto;
 min-width: 16em; width: 72%; max-width: 40em;
}
nav ul {
 position: relative;
 padding: 50%;
 max-width: 0; max-height: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 list-style: none;
 background: white;
}
nav li {
 position: absolute;
 transition: 2s;
}
.slice {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 width: 50%; height: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.unsel {
 top: 34%; left: 34%;
 width: 32%; height: 32%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 .75em;
 background: paleturquoise;
}
.coconut { transform: skewX(50deg); }
.vanilla { transform: rotate(40deg) skewX(50deg); }
.orange { transform: rotate(80deg) skewX(50deg); }
.almond { transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(50deg); }
.grape { transform: rotate(160deg) skewX(50deg); }
.blackberry { transform: rotate(-160deg) skewX(50deg); }
.cherry { transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(50deg); }
.strawberry { transform: rotate(-80deg) skewX(50deg); }
.raspberry { transform: rotate(-40deg) skewX(50deg); }
.magnifiable { height: 100%; }
nav label { cursor: pointer; }
.slice label {
 display: block;
 width: 200%; height: 200%;
 transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg);
 box-shadow: 0 0 .1em black;
 opacity: .5;
 color: transparent;
 font-size: .8em;
 line-height: 1.9;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}
.slice label:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%; left: 10%;
 width: 80%; height: 80%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 background-position: 50% 0;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 35% 35%;
 content: '';
}
.slice label:hover { opacity: 1; }
.dark label:hover { color: white; }
.light label:hover { color: black; }
.unsel label {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.5), transparent 50%);
}
.coconut label, .ococonut:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #f4f5fa; }
.vanilla label, .ovanilla:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #ffeb98; }
.orange label, .oorange:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #ffb038; }
.almond label, .oalmond:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #d3a573; }
.grape label, .ogrape:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #d9e260; }
.blackberry label, .oblackberry:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #833a68; }
.cherry label, .ocherry:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #b1001d; }
.strawberry label, .ostrawberry:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #ec0404; }
.raspberry label, .oraspberry:checked ~ nav .unsel { background: #ef6982; }
.coconut label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Cocos_nucifera00.jpg/320px-Cocos_nucifera00.jpg); }
.vanilla label:before { background-image: url(http://www.learningherbs.com/image-files/vanilla-extract-7.jpg); }
.orange label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/OrangeBloss_wb.jpg/250px-OrangeBloss_wb.jpg); }
.almond label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/PikiWiki_Israel_7025_Amond_blossom.jpg/170px-PikiWiki_Israel_7025_Amond_blossom.jpg); }
.grape label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Table_grapes_on_white.jpg/220px-Table_grapes_on_white.jpg); }
.blackberry label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Ripe%2C_ripening%2C_and_green_blackberries.jpg/220px-Ripe%2C_ripening%2C_and_green_blackberries.jpg); }
.cherry label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Cherry_Stella444.jpg/220px-Cherry_Stella444.jpg); }
.strawberry label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/PerfectStrawberry.jpg/220px-PerfectStrawberry.jpg); }
.raspberry label:before { background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Raspberries05.jpg/220px-Raspberries05.jpg); }
.slice label:hover:after { opacity: 0; }
.ococonut:checked ~ nav .coconut { transform: skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.ovanilla:checked ~ nav .vanilla { transform: rotate(40deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.oorange:checked ~ nav .orange { transform: rotate(80deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.oalmond:checked ~ nav .almond { transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.ogrape:checked ~ nav .grape { transform: rotate(160deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.oblackberry:checked ~ nav .blackberry { transform: rotate(-160deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.ocherry:checked ~ nav .cherry { transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.ostrawberry:checked ~ nav .strawberry { transform: rotate(-80deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.oraspberry:checked ~ nav .raspberry { transform: rotate(-40deg) skewX(50deg) scale(1.05); }
.ococonut:checked ~ nav .coconut label, 
.ovanilla:checked ~ nav .vanilla label, 
.oorange:checked ~ nav .orange label, 
.oalmond:checked ~ nav .almond label, 
.ogrape:checked ~ nav .grape label, 
.oraspberry:checked ~ nav .raspberry label {
 box-shadow: 0 0 .45em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 opacity: 1; color: black;
}
.oblackberry:checked ~ nav .blackberry label , 
.ocherry:checked ~ nav .cherry label, 
.ostrawberry:checked ~ nav .strawberry label {
 box-shadow: 0 0 .45em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 opacity: 1; color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 25em) { .slice label { font-size: 1em; line-height: 2.3; } }
@media (min-width: 35em) { .slice label { font-weight: 700; line-height: 2.7; } }
```

```html
<!-- content to be placed inside <body>…</body> -->
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='ococonut' class='menuopt ococonut'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='ovanilla' class='menuopt ovanilla'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='oorange' class='menuopt oorange'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='oalmond' class='menuopt oalmond'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='ogrape' class='menuopt ogrape'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='oblackberry' class='menuopt oblackberry'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='ocherry' class='menuopt ocherry'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='ostrawberry' class='menuopt ostrawberry'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='oraspberry' class='menuopt oraspberry'>
<input type='radio' name='opt' id='unsel' class='menuopt' checked>
<nav>
 <ul class='circle'>
  <li class='coconut light slice'>
    <label for='ococonut' class='circle'>Coconut</label>
  </li>
  <li class='vanilla light slice'>
    <label for='ovanilla' class='circle'>Vanilla</label>
  </li>
  <li class='orange light slice'>
    <label for='oorange' class='circle'>Orange</label>
  </li>
  <li class='almond light slice'>
    <label for='oalmond' class='circle'>Almond</label>
  </li>
  <li class='grape light slice'>
    <label for='ogrape' class='circle'>Grape</label>
  </li>
  <li class='blackberry dark slice'>
    <label for='oblackberry' class='circle'>Blackberry</label>
  </li>
  <li class='cherry dark slice'>
    <label for='ocherry' class='circle'>Cherry</label>
  </li>
  <li class='strawberry dark slice'>
    <label for='ostrawberry' class='circle'>Strawberry</label>
  </li>
  <li class='raspberry light slice'>
    <label for='oraspberry' class='circle'>Raspberry</label>
  </li>
  <li class='unsel circle'><label for='unsel'></label></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Or even [this one](http://codepen.io/frazerwilson/pen/qEdQzq)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Center the "info" bubble in the  "circle" div
  var divTop = ($("#divCircle").height() - $("#middleBubble").height()) / 2;
  var divLeft = ($("#divCircle").width() - $("#middleBubble").width()) / 2;
  $("#middleBubble").css("top", divTop + "px");
  $("#middleBubble").css("left", divLeft + "px");

  //Arrange the icons in a circle centered in the div
  numItems = $("#divCircle img").length; //How many items are in the circle?
  start = 0.0; //the angle to put the first image at. a number between 0 and 2pi
  step = (4 * Math.PI) / numItems; //calculate the amount of space to put between the items.

  //Now loop through the buttons and position them in a circle
  $("#divCircle img").each(function(index) {
    radius = ($("#divCircle").width() - $(this).width()) / 2.3; //The radius is the distance from the center of the div to the middle of an icon
    //the following lines are a standard formula for calculating points on a circle. x = cx + r * cos(a); y = cy + r * sin(a)
    //We have made adjustments because the center of the circle is not at (0,0), but rather the top/left coordinates for the center of the div
    //We also adjust for the fact that we need to know the coordinates for the top-left corner of the image, not for the center of the image.
    tmpTop = (($("#divCircle").height() / 2) + radius * Math.sin(start)) - ($(this).height() / 2);
    tmpLeft = (($("#divCircle").width() / 2) + radius * Math.cos(start)) - ($(this).width() / 2);
    start += step; //add the "step" number of radians to jump to the next icon

    //set the top/left settings for the image
    $(this).css("top", tmpTop);
    $(this).css("left", tmpLeft);
  });

});

$('.avatarList').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');
  $('#divCircle').toggleClass('expand');
});

$('#divCircle img').click(function() {
  var theSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  // alert(theSrc);
  $('.mainImg img').attr('src', theSrc);
});
```

```css
html {
  background: #f2f6f8;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f2f6f8), color-stop(50%, #d8e1e7), color-stop(51%, #b5c6d0), color-stop(100%, #e0eff9));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f6f8 0%, #d8e1e7 50%, #b5c6d0 51%, #e0eff9 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f2f6f8', endColorstr='#e0eff9', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.body {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
#divCircle {
  width: 195px;
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: -60px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0s;
}
#divCircle img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: 2px #000 solid;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}
#divCircle img:hover {
  border: 2px #333 solid;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}
#middleBubble {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #252525;
  /*#6d6e71*/
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#middleBubble img {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
}
.mainImg {
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -60px;
}
.mainImg img {
  width: 60px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  margin: 60px 0 0 60px;
}
.avatarList {
  margin: 0px -60px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*  border:1px black solid; */
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
.avatarList.expand .mainImg img {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}
#divCircle.expand {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div>Click to pick avatar</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="avatarList">
    <div class="mainImg">
      <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/i04.png">
    </div>

    <div id="divCircle">
      <div id="middleBubble"></div>
      <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/a03.png">
      <img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/c05.png">
      <img src="https://gp5.googleusercontent.com/-esaz03FKsLU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/kk0t9Rd9DB0/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg">
      <img src="http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Avatar/Face%20Avatars/Male%20Face%20G1.png">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/face-avatars/256/Female-Face-FG-1-brunette-icon.png">
      <img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/c05.png">
      <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/i04.png">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<!--body-->
```