# hollow circle with percentage color division

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on generating a hollow graph circle. Each division should span a percentage.

**Problem Statement:** if you see output, those 3 colors which forms a circle should be occupying percent of a circle. For ex if color 1 =33%, color 2=33% and color3= 33% then circle should proportion itself in three equal colors. Right now circle is not according to the percent division of colors. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Can this be achieved using html canvas?

```css
.a{
    margin: 0;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), 
                    linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(240,120,16) 100%, lightgrey 0%),
                    linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(127,127,127) 100%, lightgrey 0%),
                    linear-gradient(310deg, rgb(255,192,0) 100%, lightgrey 0%);
    
    background-position: center center, left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom;
    background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: Would use SVG instead of plain CSS for this.

Comment: You asked an identical question less than an hour ago, which got closed due to "Unclear what you are asking". How are you expecting this question to do better if you repeatedly ask it?

Comment: right connexo.... if question is not clear give the person time to update it. Have patience... blessings

Comment: @H.B. any links for SVG tutorial would help

Comment: Search MDN, it has a lot of info on it.

Comment: I cannot see any updates as compared to the closed previous question of yours.

Comment: what is not clear in the question @connexo. If you are not interested the n do not visit.

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789300/multi-coloured-circular-div-using-background-colours/47789489#47789489

Answer (score 3):

You may adjust the code like this:

```css
.a{
    margin: 0;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size:50% 100% ,100% 50%,100% 100%;
    background-position:100% 0,0 100%,0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(33deg,transparent 37%, green 0),     
    linear-gradient(-33deg, red 70%, blue 0%),     
    linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, green 50%);
    position:relative;
}
.a:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
  left:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

By the way it's more suitable to consider SVG or more accurate tools to create chart like this. Here is an idea with SVG:

```css
.pie {
  width: 100px;
}

.pie circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray:55 110
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
  <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%"  stroke="red">
  </circle>
  <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%"  stroke=" green" stroke-dashoffset=" -55">
  </circle>
  <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke="blue" stroke-dashoffset="-110">
  </circle>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: What is the logic here..... what if the percentage of colors vary here? What is that formula to manage the colors percentage right?

Comment: @Akki619 there is no generic formula to achieve this in this way or in CSS in general :) i adjusted the code to show you how you can have 33% for all, and i shared another link to also show you another example ... i would say you have to handle each case separately as this is not the purpose of CSS ... if you want something accurate you need to consider more techniques like SVG or some chart plugin ... i will add an example with SVG

Comment: @Akki619 i added another way with SVG and here also you won't have the 33% explicit but you need to understand how stroke work so you can adjust it