How to remove thin line between touching diagonal borders CSS
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it so the thin line between borders that are on a diagonal go away.

I've tried adding margin: -1px;  to .circle-container, .segment and .segment1, 2 and 3 with no success.
I've tried changing the segment rotation to have segments overlap.
I've tried changing the skew to also make the segments overlap.
I think because the intersection of the borders is on a diagonal, overlapping them won't fix this problem, I could totally be wrong about that though.

I'm just not sure what to try next.



.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: transparent;
  visibility: false;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -1px;
}

.segment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.segment::after {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.segment:hover {
  background: lightcyan;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.segment1 {
  background: #091862;
  border: 10px ghostwhite solid;
}

.segment2 {
  background: #245ab2;
  border: 10px ghostwhite solid;
}

.segment3 {
  background: #2fc0dd;
  border: 10px ghostwhite solid;
}

.cutout {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: visible;
}
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="segment segment1" style="transform: rotate(0deg) skew(18deg)"></div>
    <div class="segment segment2" style="transform: rotate(72deg) skew(18deg)"></div>
    <div class="segment segment3" style="transform: rotate(144deg) skew(18deg)"></div>
    <div class="segment segment1" style="transform: rotate(216deg) skew(18deg)"></div>
    <div class="segment segment2" style="transform: rotate(288deg) skew(18deg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cutout"></div>
</div>




Frankly SVG would be simpler - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943053/how-to-create-a-circle-with-links-on-border-side

it's a coloring glitch, I don't think it could be removed. you should change to SVG.

@MisterJojo Thank you both for the prompt responses!! Each segment needs to react to an onclick event, would an SVG still work for this?

Yes, any SVG element is clickable, in the same way as any html element, with an addEventListener, for example.
